# How to build Json 'body' of http call to API

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am trying to contact a GraphQL API and retrieve the data in Flutter

I have a working call in postman giving me the data back.

I have been referred to an example of a working http call but can't get the body to work. I used an encoded version in my postman call but have been advised to un-encode the `"data-raw"` of my Postman call and pass `Json` into the `query`.

I have the main `query` and then the `variable` which is the `lat/long`

A) Is this the correct approach, using pure Json as opposed to encoded like in my postman call (Example below)

```
    {"query":"query ($lat: Float!, $lng: Float!) {\n  vehicles(lat: $lat, lng: $lng) {\n    id\n...
```

B) How can I get the query and variable into the `Map data =` if this is the correct thing to do?

Here is where I am at, using un-encoded Json in `Map data =` which isn't being accepted and the `$lat $long` aren't transferred into `query` from `variables`

```
Future<http.Response> showMicroMob () async {

  var url ='https://flow-api.fluctuo.com/v1?access_token=my_token';

  Map data = {
    'query': query ($lat: Float!, $lng: Float!) {
  vehicles (lat: $lat, lng: $lng) {
    id  
    type
    publicId
    provider {
      slug
    }
    lat
    lng
    propulsion
    battery
    attributes
    ... on Station {
      isVirtual
      availableVehicles
      availableStands
      stationVehicleDetails {
        vehicleType
        propulsion
        availableVehicles
      }
      vehicles {
        id
        publicId
        type
        propulsion
        battery
      }
    }
  }
}
    'variables': {"lat":51.492591,"lng":-0.157221}
  };

  //encode Map to JSON
  var body = json.encode(data);

  var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url),
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
      body: body
  );
  print("${response.statusCode}");
  print("${response.body}");
  return response;
}
```

Original example

```
Future<http.Response> postRequest () async {
  var url ='https://pae.ipportalegre.pt/testes2/wsjson/api/app/ws-authenticate';

  Map data = {
    'apikey': '12345678901234567890'
  }
  //encode Map to JSON
  var body = json.encode(data);

  var response = await http.post(url,
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
      body: body
  );
  print("${response.statusCode}");
  print("${response.body}");
  return response;
}
```

Update of call

If I shift variable up to make a complete String it no longer recognises the `$lat $long` fields or the actual `lat/long` numbers as values and makes them orange text. When I move variables down like in my postman request it of course throws errors, but the numbers are recognised as such ($Lat/$Long still not able to take the value. Tried just hard placing lat/ling figures in and returned

```
    flutter: 400 flutter: Bad Request
```

Should I try passing the variables in another way?

```
Future<http.Response> showMicroMob () async {

  var url ='https://flow-api.fluctuo.com/v1?access_token=x';
    


  var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url),
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
      body: utf8.encode(r'{"query":"query ($lat: Float!, $lng: Float!) {\n  vehicles(lat: $lat, lng: $lng) {\n    id\n    lat\n    lng\n    type\n    publicId\n    attributes\n    propulsion\n    battery\n    provider {\n      name\n      slug\n      website\n      discountCode\n      app {\n        android\n        ios\n        __typename\n      }\n      deepLink {\n        android\n        ios\n        __typename\n      }\n      stationVehicleTypes\n      __typename\n    }\n    pricing {\n      currency\n      unlock\n      perKm {\n        start\n        interval\n        price\n        __typename\n      }\n      perMin {\n        start\n        interval\n        price\n        __typename\n      }\n      perMinPause {\n        start\n        interval\n        price\n        __typename\n      }\n      includeVat\n      __typename\n    }\n    ... on Station {\n      availableVehicles\n      availableStands\n      isVirtual\n      stationVehicleDetails {\n        vehicleType\n        propulsion\n        availableVehicles\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    ... on Car {\n      carClass\n      carModel\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n"
      ,"variables":{"lat":51.492591,"lng":-0.157221}}'));

  print("${response.statusCode}");
  print("${response.body}");
  return response;
}
```

Comment: You can either build a `Map<String, dynamic>` and then `json.encode` it, but if your json is very simple and doesn't change much there's really no reason why you shouldn't build it as a string and then do `body: utf8.encode(myHandCraftedJsonString),`

Comment: To build it as a String how do I structure Query & Variable (Lat/Long)? Do I place them together into the one String to become ```body:```? Thank you

Comment: (Have added update of my successful postman call body in raw format)

Comment: Stick that entire string you just updated into `body: utf8.encode(r'{"query......221}}'),`

Comment: Thanks, have done so and tried lots of ways to make it function but haven't managed to. Have updated question with where I stand incase you can see what I'm doing wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a bunch of typos in your raw string. The following works, and answers your earlier question about how to build via JSON (as an alternative).

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() async {
  {
    var url = 'https://flow-api.fluctuo.com/v1'
        '?access_token=eOy6L54RIbbswB8O0gQgk3lChcCu2wco';

    final encodedQuery1 = r'''{
  "query": "query ($lat: Float!, $lng: Float!) {vehicles(lat: $lat, lng: $lng) {  id  lat   lng   type   publicId   attributes  propulsion  battery  provider {   name  slug     website      discountCode     app {      android      ios      __typename     }     deepLink {        android      ios       __typename      }      stationVehicleTypes      __typename    }    pricing {      currency      unlock      perKm {        start        interval        price        __typename      }      perMin {        start        interval        price        __typename      }      perMinPause {        start        interval        price        __typename      }      includeVat      __typename    }    ... on Station {      availableVehicles      availableStands      isVirtual      stationVehicleDetails {        vehicleType        propulsion        availableVehicles        __typename      }      __typename    }    ... on Car {      carClass      carModel      __typename    }    __typename  }}  ",
  "variables": {
    "lat": 51.492591,
    "lng": -0.157221
  }
}
''';

    // ALTERNATIVE way to build the json
    final lat = 51.492591;
    final long = -0.157221;
    final gqlQuery =
        r'query ($lat: Float!, $lng: Float!) {vehicles(lat: $lat, lng: $lng) {  id  lat   lng   type   publicId   attributes  propulsion  battery  provider {   name  slug     website      discountCode     app {      android      ios      __typename     }     deepLink {        android      ios       __typename      }      stationVehicleTypes      __typename    }    pricing {      currency      unlock      perKm {        start        interval        price        __typename      }      perMin {        start        interval        price        __typename      }      perMinPause {        start        interval        price        __typename      }      includeVat      __typename    }    ... on Station {      availableVehicles      availableStands      isVirtual      stationVehicleDetails {        vehicleType        propulsion        availableVehicles        __typename      }      __typename    }    ... on Car {      carClass      carModel      __typename    }    __typename  }}';
    final encodedQuery2 = json.encode({
      'query': gqlQuery,
      'variables': {'lat': lat, 'lng': long},
    });
    // END of alternative

    var response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(url),
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: utf8.encode(encodedQuery1), // to use the alternative replace 1 w/ 2
    );

    print('${response.statusCode}');
    print('${response.body}');
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

copy your response and past it on [quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io/).
**quicktype** will give you a model class.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).